# how to install debian to Windows 7 from disk?

Tags: windows-7, debian

my OS is Windows 7 and I want install Debian, I have download Debian `.iso`, how could I install it from disk, I try to use `grub4dos`, I extract `grldr` to my `C:\` ,but there is already a file called `grldr`, can `grub4dos`'s `grldr` file  replace Windows 7 's `grldr` file?

[image]

Comment: Do you want to dual boot or do you want Debain to be the only OS on the system?

Comment: i want dual boot

Answer (score 3):

To install with just the ISO, take a look at [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/). It allows you to create a bootable USB drive for installation, or perform a "frugal" install directly from the ISO to a partition.

[image]

Comment: i want use "frugal" install ,but debian 's website say The installer cannot boot from files on an NTFS file system.  my c:\ is ntfs ,and UNetbootin extract the iso to c:\

Comment: @user41775 You can use a partition tool to prepare a separate (even FAT32) partition and move the files there. None are over 4GiB and the installer should let you format a partition in ext3/4.

Comment: @user41775 Where does "debian 's website say The installer cannot boot from files on an NTFS file system" ?

Answer (score 1):

You do not specify exactly what you want to do.  Assuming you want to dual boot simply follow the instructions [here](http://apcmag.com/how_to_dualboot_vista_with_linux_vista_installed_first.htm).  Best dual boot guide I have ever seen.  The link I provided is for Linux + Vista (Vista Installed First) but the steps are the same with Windows 7.

Comment: i open this link ,but got this message "You are not authorized to view this page"

Comment: @user41775 I don't know why you got that message, the link works fine. Is your computer running some kind of censoring software like WebSense?